# Gridlines showing on my teechart graph in .net

Tags: vb.net, teechart

So I have a TeeChart graph in VB.net winForms.

It has a few logarithmic gridlines on it.

[image: Few gridlines]

However, when I add labels, I get extra gridlines too. I never wanted these there, and I'm wondering if anyone's got ideas on how to get rid of them.
This is the code I ran:

```
tcRPP.Axes.Bottom.Labels.Items.Clear()
tcRPP.Axes.Bottom.Labels.Items.Add(xMin / 2.3D, "Points in bucket:")

For Each group In xGrouped
    tcRPP.Axes.Bottom.Labels.Items.Add(group.Average(Function(point) point.X), CStr(group.Count()))
Next
```

My graph now looks like this:

[image: Many gridlines]

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I hid the graph altogether by saying:

```
    Dim pointSeries As Series = chartseriesAsList().FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.GetType() = GetType(Points3D))

    Dim xAxis = pointSeries.GetHorizAxis
    xAxis.Grid.Visible = false

    Dim yAxis = pointSeries.GetVertAxis
    yAxis.Grid.Visible = false
```